# Updating TextView with data read from bluetooth module

Tags: java, android, multithreading, bluetooth

What I'm trying to do is to constantly update a `TextView` once I read a new line from a `BufferedReader` that reads serial data from a *Bluetooth* module. Currently, the data gets displayed once, then the connection is closed and nothing happens.

Shouldn't `content()` and `refresh()` functions call each other up endlessly, so that the connection is never closed?

Here's my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final UUID mUUID = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805F9B34FB");

    String line;
    int cnt = 0;
    BluetoothSocket btSocket = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    TextView data;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        data = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.data);
        BluetoothAdapter bt = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        System.out.println(bt.getBondedDevices());
        BluetoothDevice hc06 = bt.getRemoteDevice("00:14:03:05:5A:94");
        System.out.println(hc06.getName());

        do {
            try {
                btSocket = hc06.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mUUID);
                System.out.println(btSocket);
                btSocket.connect();
                System.out.println(btSocket.isConnected());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            cnt++;
        } while(!btSocket.isConnected()&& (cnt < 5));

        content();

        try {
            btSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
   public void content() {
       try {
           in = btSocket.getInputStream();
           br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
           line = br.readLine();
           System.out.println(line);
           refresh();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

    private void refresh(){
        final Handler handler = new Handler();

        final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                data.setText(line);
                content();
            }
        };
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 100);
    }
}
```